# Lua How to replace 1 specific character inside table without whole string?

Tags: lua

Already know how to show specific character.

```
table {"abc"}
return string.sub(table[1], 2, 2)
b
```

But want to replace 1 specific character inside the table **without** changing whole string.

```
table = {"abc"}
```

to

```
table = {"axc"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lua, strings are strictly immutable, so they cannot be *changed*, per se.

As such, the only way to accomplish this is to create a new string with the content you want and insert it in `table[1]`. Whether or not the string is inside a table does not matter.

This would be accomplished, for example, by taking the beginning and end of the string and concatenating them with the new part:

```
local index = 2 -- The character we want to change
table[1] = string.sub(table[1], 1, index - 1) .. "x" .. string.sub(table[1], index + 1, -1)
```

This would extract all characters from the beginning of the string until the character before the one we wish to "replace", append the new character, then append the rest of the old string not including the character we "replaced".

In most cases, however, it is not very well-advised to play with single characters like this, as Lua has reasonably powerful pattern-matching and replacement facilities such as [string.gsub](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub), which allows you to replace even more complex substrings with ease. (Usage example from Programming in Lua available [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html))